# Software not accessible after clicking on it . Error showing

Tags: software-rec, javascript

Software not accessible after clicking on it . Error showing - screenshot pasted

[image]

Comment: That's way few details to give you anything useful. What is the software? How exactly you get the error?... Have you tried to reinstall it? Does it work on another device?

Comment: Do you use any security software?

Comment: "`The system cannot find the file specified`" - does it exist? Can you run it from the command line? Have you checked permissions?